# FrameLayout does not match the height of NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout, nestedscrollview

I have a FrameLayout inside a NestedScrollView, as

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000">
```

But the FrameLayout is not filling the height of the NestedScrollView. How might I fix this?

Comment: I think set gravity = center or other in frame layout

Comment: doing `android:layout_gravity="center"`  or `android:layout_gravity="center|fill_vertical"` does not seem to work

Comment: `android:fillViewport="true"`check this Add it in `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Check This Solution
Use `fillViewport="true"`
this attribute causes the scroll view’s child to expand to the height of the ScrollView if needed. When the child is taller than the ScrollView, the attribute has no effect.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Comment: I had already tried `android:fillViewport="true"`. But when I do I get a nullPointerException at line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: Ok I got it I think you should use this whole `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` inside linear layout

Comment: It seems something else was causing the crash. So thanks (although I had already tried fillViewport). I clean the project and now it's working and I don't know why it was failing.

Comment: This worked like a charm with android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

Comment: you guys doing guess work. whats wrong actually? Why is it not working?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: you are a big hero!

Comment: Thank you very much!.

Comment: works also with `androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout` and `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView` - Thanks!