# Fab bar not showing over nested scroll view

Tags: java, android, android-nestedscrollview

I have followed many answers and tried to show fab bar over nested scroll view but i failed to achieve this

my xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:scrollingCache="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/billBlock"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/allJobsheetList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_mic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tint="@color/grey_80"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/grey_20"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mic" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_call"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tint="@color/grey_80"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/grey_20"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_photo_camera" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/showFilterView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

in the above xml fab bar showing at the end of nested scroll view not in fixed position on bottom right.i am new to android can any one help me how i can achieve this

[How to add floating action button on top of scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651418/how-to-add-floating-action-button-on-top-of-scrollview)

[Create the Layout with CardView and Floating Action Button Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238880/create-the-layout-with-cardview-and-floating-action-button-android)

[FrameLayout does not match the height of NestedScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962307/framelayout-does-not-match-the-height-of-nestedscrollview/33962667)

Comment: align parent bottom and align parent right are used in relative layouts to fix the views in bottom/right respectively. It does not fix the view in this case, you can add margin from bottom to the nested scrollview ,and giving a height to the linear layout accordingly.

Comment: To align a child respective to another in Coordinator Layout, use anchor or layout  gravity  to give it a gravity, and to take advantage of coordinator behaviour make the fab  direct children of the coordinator layout.

Comment: @Kaveri.can you provide sample code.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have made a few changes , made fab the direct child of coordinator layout and used archor `app:layout_anchor="@id/nested_scroll_view" 
 app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"` and  for aligning fabs relative to the nested scrollview .

```
`<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:scrollingCache="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/billBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/allJobsheetList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<!--<LinearLayout-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:gravity="center_horizontal"-->

    <!---->
    <!--android:orientation="vertical">-->


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_mic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/nested_scroll_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_call"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/nested_scroll_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:fabSize="mini"

        app:srcCompat="@drawable/exo_controls_play" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/showFilterView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/nested_scroll_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/exo_controls_next" />
<!--</LinearLayout>-->
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: @Kaveri.Thanks i did this already but now my problem is i need to hide bottom navigation view on scroll  but i have nested scroll in every fragment

Comment: Sorry for late response, so do u mean to hide (animate)bottom bar on scroll and show it on reverse scroll?

Comment: @Kaveri.yes exactly right.before i did it using frame layout inside nested scroll view but if i add so then my fab will not positon properly

Comment: One way to achieve this behaviour is  by setting the layout_behaviour for the bottom- bar , but this requires coordinator layout as the root parent. This link might help you :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715732/how-to-scroll-up-down-of-bottom-bar-on-scrolling-of-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

This layout will work fine. Please check if you have ic_add, ic_mic, ic_photo_camera in res/drawable folder. Removing these, i can see the view like below
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMSVf.png)

Comment: i can see icon but if you have large content rows in scroll then it show at the end of the ciew